# Post Request With HttpUrlConnection Though a Proxy

Tags: java, proxy

i want to create a Post Request With `HttpUrlConnection` Though a Proxy. but I can't fine any way to do that!!

`URL.openConnection(Proxy proxy)` is a GET only method!
also `UrlConnection` does not have any method to set Proxy!

Bye the way I don't want to use any http-clients as they are not working for me.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "I don't want to use any http-clients as they are not working for me"?

Comment: Maybe your real question should be "http-clients are not working for me"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create a Post Request With HttpUrlConnection Though a Proxy.

Like so:

```
URL url; // ...
Proxy proxy; // ...
HttpURLConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
conn.setDoOutput(true); // changes the request method to POST
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
// Write the POST parameters to 'out'
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode == 200)
{
    // read response from conn.getInputStream();
}
else
{
    // read error from conn.getErrorStream();
}
```

> I can't find any way to do that!!
>   URL.openConnection(Proxy proxy) is a GET only method!

I'm not aware of any evidence for that statement, or any reason why it might be true. It isn't mentioned in the Javadoc. What's your basis for that claim?

> also UrlConnection does not have any method to set Proxy!

It doesn't need one, see above.